# How to pass variable of one Test Method to another Test Method in C#?

Tags: c#

I have to utilize the value of a string variable that is initialized in one test method and I want that same to be used in the next Test Method

Eg: TestMethod1 is as below:
I am having a registration form in that I am having a username field.

I am passing username: "Test123" with sendkeys() ----->(this is coming from excel)
now if I rerun the script I got an error as "Username already exist please enter unique username"

for this problem, I created a function for appending a random string to the username. so the new username will be "Test123SomeRandomstring" ----> **This is stored in the string variable in TestMethod1**

Now I am having an issue with my next test method which is as below (TestMethod2) which is login TestMethod:

**Now When I am trying to Login with the help of the username I need that string variable from TestMethod1 to be used for login in TestMethod2.**

Can Anyone Help with this?

Thanks in Advance.

**Note: I have to create the above code in C# only**

```cs
[TestMethod]
public virtual void TestRegristration()
{
    try
    {
        LoginPage ObjLoginPage = LoginPage.GetInstance(this);

        var generator = new GenerateRandomString();

        var randomString = generator.RandomString();

        ObjLoginPage.enterUserName(1, ObjExcelHelper, Driver, "UserName",randomString);//Enter Usernamewith some random string

        ObjLoginPage.enterPassword(1, ObjExcelHelper, Driver, "Password");//Enter Password, Confirm Password and Click Register Button
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public virtual void TestLoginWithValidCredential()
{
    try
    {
        LoginPage ObjLoginPage = LoginPage.GetInstance(this);
        
        ObjLoginPage.enterUserName(1, ObjExcelHelper, Driver, "UserName");//need to pass randomString here with username from TestMethod1

        //ObjLoginPage.enterPassword(1, ObjExcelHelper, Driver, "Password");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}

public class GenerateRandomString
{
    public string RandomString()
    {
        int length = 5;

        // creating a StringBuilder object()
        StringBuilder str_build = new StringBuilder();
        Random random = new Random();

        char letter;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            double flt = random.NextDouble();
            int shift = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(25 * flt));
            letter = Convert.ToChar(shift + 65);
            str_build.Append(letter);
        }
        //System.Console.WriteLine(str_build.ToString());
        return str_build.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not good practive to have such dependencies between test methods. Test cases should be runnable in isolation and in any order. One way to do this is to create the random user name in a `[ClassInitialize]` method once before all tests in the class.

Comment: BTW. Why are your test methods virtual?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally individual tests should be self contained and you should not rely on the test order.

The next best thing is the constructor. In MS Test the constructor is called once.

The also is [ClassInitializeAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms245248(v=vs.100)) or event AssemblyInitialize attribute (but they are `static` which I find limiting). Here are the official [Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/ms245248(v=vs.100)#examples):

> ```
>    [TestClass()]
>    public sealed class DivideClassTest
>    {
>        [AssemblyInitialize()]
>        public static void AssemblyInit(TestContext context)
>        {
>            MessageBox.Show("AssemblyInit " + context.TestName);
>        }
>
>        [ClassInitialize()]
>        public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
>        {
>            MessageBox.Show("ClassInit " + context.TestName);
>        }
> ```

However for your scenario maybe a string, possibly `static readonly` is enough.

```
private static readonly Test UserId = ...
```

A helper method could create the user if it doesn't exist or gets the id if it already exists.

---

Update

```
[TestClass()]
public class MyTestClass
{
  private string TestId {get; set;}

  public MyTestClass() 
  {
      var generator = new GenerateRandomString();
      TestId = generator.RandomString();

  [TestMethod]
  public void TestRegristration()
        {
           ...
           ObjLoginPage.enterUserName(1, ObjExcelHelper, Driver, "UserName",TestId );
```

or

```
[TestClass()]
public class MyTestClass
{
  private static string TestId {get; set;}

  [ClassInitialize()]
  public static void ClassInit(TestContext context)
  {
      var generator = new GenerateRandomString();
      TestId = generator.RandomString();
  }

  [TestMethod]
  public void TestRegristration()
  {
      ...
      ObjLoginPage.enterUserName(1, ObjExcelHelper, Driver, "UserName",TestId );
```

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail how I can use [ClassInitialize] in my method?